# How to convert Object to Serializable in java

Tags: java, serialization

this question is very simple but i don't think that the answer is as such given that i haven't found anything around the internet to do what i want to achieve. I have two classes: GenericModel and GenericBean. Thos classes contains a map, Both of them. The code is the following:

```
public class GenericBean implements IsSerializable {
    Map<String, Serializable> properties = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();

    public Object getProperty(String key){

        return properties.get(key);
    }

    public void setProperty(String key, Serializable value){
        properties.put(key, value);
    }

    public Map<String, Serializable> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    public void setProperties(Map<String, Serializable> properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }
}
```

The second:

```
public class GenericModel {
private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GenericModel.class);

public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
    return properties;
}

public Object getProperty(String key) {
    return properties.get(key);
}

public void setProperty(String key, Object value) {
    properties.put(key, value);
}

public void setProperties(Map<String, Object> properties) {
    this.properties = properties;
}

private Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

}

What i want to achieve is to copy the map Properties of GenericModel in the map Properties of Generic bean.

But i get a compilation error, cause the `Map<String,Object>` is not compatible with the `Map<String,Serializable>` What should i do?

Comment: Use casting, and pray that all your values indeed are serializable. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: Does using a `Map<String, Serializable> properties` would be a solution ? and cast when using the `setProperty` method

Comment: What would you expect to happen when the Object-Map contains an item which is not Serializable? There is no instant solution as the Maps are not compatible with each other. You always have to decide what to do with these edge cases (drop them, throw an Exception, ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

- iterate the "source map"
- for each key/value where the value is `instanceof` Serializable - you add that key/value pair to the "sink" map
- and as mentioned in the many comments: at least theoretically you need to think up what to do about values that do not implement that interface

Answer (score 2):

If you will decide to use casting, you might use `Stream` for this. 
All non-serializable properties will be ignored in this case:

```
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put("ser", "String");
properties.put("non ser", new Object());

Map<String, Serializable> serializableMap = properties.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() instanceof Serializable)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> (Serializable) e.getValue()));

System.out.println(serializableMap); //{ser=String}
```